# LWC cannot render String from Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to set up the easiest LWC, but I'm getting this error:

> t=>{const r=e(t);return Promise.resolve(r).then(e=>{if("Error"===e.state)throw e.error;return e.data})}

Can you please tell me what I'm missing?

**SalesLeadUIController.cls**

```
public without sharing class SalesLeadUIController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getCurrentFormattedTime() {
        return Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
    }
}
```

**SalesLeadUI.js**

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import getCurrentFormattedTime from '@salesforce/apex/SalesLeadUIController.getCurrentFormattedTime';

export default class SalesLeadUi extends LightningElement {
    dateTimeValue = getCurrentFormattedTime;
}
```

**SalesLeadUI.html**

```
<template>
    <div>{dateTimeValue}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getCurrentFormattedTime` - is an imported async function, which should be called as a function `getCurrentFormattedTime()`.

you can call it, for example, for a `connectedCallback` lifecycle function:

```
import {LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
import getCurrentFormattedTime from '@salesforce/apex/SalesLeadUIController.getCurrentFormattedTime';

export default class SalesLeadUi extends LightningElement {
    @track dateTimeValue;

    connectedCallback(){
        getCurrentFormattedTime().then(
            result => {this.dateTimeValue = result;})
        .catch (e => {catch error here});
    }
}
```

this is an imperative calling.

you can call it also using async-await

```
import {LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
import getCurrentFormattedTime from '@salesforce/apex/SalesLeadUIController.getCurrentFormattedTime';

export default class SalesLeadUi extends LightningElement {
    @track dateTimeValue;

    async connectedCallback(){
        try{
            this.dateTimeValue = await getCurrentFormattedTime();
        }catch (e) {
             //handle error here
        }
    }
}
```

---

in addition to it, you call it  using `wire` decorator

**JS**

```
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getCurrentFormattedTime from @salesforce/apex/SalesLeadUIController.getCurrentFormattedTime';

export default class SalesLeadUi extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getCurrentFormattedTime) dateTimeValue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <template if:true={dateTimeValue.data}>
        <div>{dateTimeValue.data}</div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Also *wire* didn't work for me, only track.

Comment: @please check, I've updated the answer for `wire`. the rendered part should be as `{dateTimeValue.data}`

Comment: Still not working with `wire`, however, first 2 approaches are perfectly suitable for me, thank you!